# Run a VBS file using Javascript in a Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, vbscript

I am making a chrome extension to fill out a form, but for some reason, it doesn't work with changing the values so I have to simulate that I am the user and press some buttons then TAB and so on.
I am trying to run a VBS file using a Javascript file. Is there a way to do this? If not, is there another way to do this?

Edit:

Here is my manifest.json file:

```
"name": "something",
"version": "1.0",
"manifest_version": 2,
"content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": ["the url of the form..."],
        "js": ["javascript.js"]
    }
]
```

Here is my javascript.js file:

```
window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementsByName("name")[0].select(); //Selects the first input field
    //Now I want to type in my name
    //Then press TAB
    //Now I want to type in my email address
};
```

Comment: You can register the vbs script and run it using [nativeMessaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging). However filling out forms is possible using the standard JavaScript method `document.execCommand` and `dispatchEvent` when performed correctly, but I can't help without more context ([MCVE](/help/mcve)).

Comment: @wOxxOm Can you give me an example of how to use document.exeCommand and dispatchEvent. There is a form with input fields under each other. I have to type in my name and than press tab and than type in my email can you give me an example on how you would do it?

Comment: Examples of using these methods are plenty and trivial to find. I would need a real context/[MCVE](/help/mcve) to provide anything better.

Comment: @wOxxOm If there are plenty examples can you tell me what to write in my js file to type in my name and then press tab and type in my email for example. This is the real context.

Comment: I've used the term "context" in the technical sense as an alias for [MCVE](/help/mcve). You didn't provide it neither in the question nor in the comments so I can't help.

Comment: @wOxxOm I edited my question. I provided my code.

Comment: As per the examples and documentation for execCommand you need to focus the element first: document.getElementsByName("name")[0].focus(); document.execCommand('insertText', false, 'foo'); and then repeat the same for each element you want to set.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thank you very much for helping. It worked. But I have another question. How can I press TAB with this? Because I can't use document.getElemetsByName("name") for all the elements.

Comment: You can focus the next element directly using .focus(), and to select the next element use an appropriate selector with document.querySelector or just use nextElementSibling like document.getElementsByName("name")[0].nextElementSibling

Comment: @wOxxOm I tried but unfortunately document.getElementsByName("name")[0].nextElementSibling.focus(); doesn't work because it is null. I also tryed document.querySelector and that is null too. Do you know any other way of simulating TAB.

Comment: Like I said it's impossible to help without MCVE, at least an excerpt of HTML.

Comment: @wOxxOm So I have the two input field one is the 'name' that is successfully accessed but the other one doesn't have a name, class stb... Only way to access it is to press TAB.

Comment: Programming doesn't work like that. Without MCVE (meaning an excerpt of HTML) I can't help.

Comment: @wOxxOm What do you mean by Programming doesn't work like that? When I press the TAB button and i jumps to the other input field, that is programmed too. Here is the page: https://stripe-payments-demo.appspot.com/ and name, email, address, city, state, zip, country work but I cant access the Card Number.

Comment: Looking at the demo page, you (likely) wont be able to set (or read) the data in that element due to cross-origin (xss). Chrome can fill those forms for you if you're logged in, and there's no good reason to scrape the data....

Comment: @BalázsZsömböly, I mean programming is a precise thing that needs actual precise info like [MCVE](/help/mcve), not just descriptions. In this case the card number is inside a cross-origin iframe so you can't access it directly, you need to declare your content script to run inside that iframe URL by adding it in `"matches"` in manifest.json, so there'll be two instances of your content script - one for the main fields and another for the card input.

Comment: My question is that is there a way to press TAB (or simulate a TAB key function)? I think this would be the easiest way to fill out the form.